# What is the set of positive integers $n$ such that $(6k+2)^n + 3$ and $(6k+2)^n + 5$ are both prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

That is, for some fixed $k\in N$, what is the set of positive integers $n$ such that $(6k+2)^n+3$ and $(6k+2)^n+5$ are both prime? At least, is this set finite?

Comment: If we knew it was infinite, then the [twin primes conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) would be solved. So the only possible answers (currently) regarding its size are "finite" or "unknown".

Comment: As $2^n=(3-1)^n\equiv1\pmod 3$ if $n$ is even,  then $(6k+2)^n+5\equiv 0\pmod 3,$ hence composite ,so $n$ must be odd

Comment: If $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ then $2^n\equiv 2 \pmod 5$. So, $n=1$ or $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$.  Similarly, $n\not\equiv 1\pmod 6$ if $n>1$.

Comment: Let's pretend that the twin prime conjecture is true. As such, I am interested in finding the exact set for $n$, or at least if there is a proof that it is for sure finite.

Comment: This will not help you in this case. If we pretented it were wrong, then you can deduce, that this set is finite, _not_ conversely.

Comment: Still, the only answer you are likely to be able to get is negative. Knowing the TPC doesn't really help with this problem.

Comment: I added the "for some $k$" in your title, to reflect what you wrote .

Comment: The case where $6k+2$ happens to be a power of two, in particular the cases $k=0$ and $k=1$, are covered by [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70682/11619).